# Bluetooth not working on Windows 8.1, but worked on Windows 10 (running on a MacBook Air)

Tags: mac, windows-8.1, bluetooth, macbook, boot-camp

I can't get Bluetooth to work on my MacBook Air 1,1 2008 when running Windows 8.1. The Bluetooth card shows up as working in the Device Manager but none of the Bluetooth options in Settings or Control Panel exist.

I used the Boot Camp drivers and everything else works fine.

Bluetooth works in MacOS and previously worked in Windows 10 and Linux Mint on the same machine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was to roll back the driver from the 2015 version to the 2010 version, bluetooth icon popped straight back into the task bar when I did that! I used Snappy Driver Installer and checked the "older" box to find an older driver that worked.